# c# FsCheck cannot convert lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, fscheck

I'm trying to get a C# FsCheck generator to generate a series
of commands which are initialized with random strings. I came up with
the following solution:

```
public Gen<Command<A,B>> Next(B value)
{
  var gen1 = Arb.Default.String().Generator;
  var gen2 = Gen.two(gen1);
  var gen3 = gen2.select((Command<A,B>)(s => new DerivedCommand(s.Item1,s.Item2))) 
  //DerivedCommand extends Command<A,B>

  return Gen.OneOf(gen3);
}
```

However, VS cannot build this code:

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to type Command<A,B> because it is not a delegate type
```

I have searched solutions for this error message, but nothing I found helped.
I am using *System.Linq* and *System.Data.Entity*. Any suggestions for resolving this issue are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to cast `(s => new DerivedCommand(s.Item1,s.Item2))`, which is a lambda expression, to `(Command<A,B>)`, which (I assume) is a class.

You probably need something like:

```
var gen3 = gen2.select(s => (Command<A,B>)(new DerivedCommand(s.Item1,s.Item2)));
```